# Slighthly skewed graph for SVM training

Tags: machine-learning, octave, svm

I'm taking ML classes on coursera and my SVMtraining code is correct but the graph doesn't match the solution provided in pdf. And i don't understand why or what's the problem in my code.

Following is my solution. I've also attached the graphs, first is the provided solution, the other is mine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdCJ7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/benLv.png)

```
 function [C, sigma] = dataset3Params(X, y, Xval, yval)

 C = 1;
 sigma = 0.3;

 vals= [0.01 0.03 0.1 0.3 1 3 10 30];
 err=1000000000;

 for i=1:8
 for j= 1:8

 ex_C=vals(i);
 ex_sigma=vals(j);

 model=svmTrain(X, y, ex_C, @(x1,x2) gaussianKernel(x1,x2,ex_sigma));

 predictions = svmPredict(model, Xval);
 sam_err= mean(double(predictions ~= yval));

 if sam_err <= err
 C=ex_C;
 sigma=ex_sigma;
 err=sam_err;

 end 

 end

 end
```

Comment: Your code seems OK. Maybe you messed up in the part where you plot a graph.

Comment: Graph code seems to malfunction here: 
contour(X1, X2, vals, [0.5 1.5] , 'lineColor', 'b');

It doesn't display dataset2 Decision boundary but does for dataset 3 which is skewed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I remember now. There was a bug in code. Try this: `contour(X1, X2, vals, [0:1] , 'lineColor', 'b');`.

Comment: Indeed I remember there was some bug in code which was discussed in tutorial/discussion part of that week

Comment: It still doesn't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the contour should be `contour(X1, X2, vals, [0.5 0.5], 'b');`